# Browser-sync (under gulp) doesn't refresh browser

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-livereload, browser-sync

My config does everything it's supposed to, but it never refreshes the browser. Once I refresh it manually, changes are there. I am connecting to the default localhost:3000. Any ideas why is it so or how to debug it?

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('html', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./app/scss/*.scss', ['sass', browserSync.reload]);
    gulp.watch('./app/*.html', ['html', browserSync.reload]);

});
```

example of a console output:

```
[BS] Local URL: http://localhost:3000
[BS] External URL: http://192.168.1.3:3000
[BS] Serving files from: app
[17:10:32] Starting 'html'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[17:10:32] Finished 'html' after 829 μs
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[17:10:42] Starting 'sass'...
[BS] 1 file changed (style.css)
[17:10:42] Finished 'sass' after 22 ms
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[17:11:02] Starting 'html'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[17:11:02] Finished 'html' after 472 μs
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

Comment: Even i faced a similar problem when i was new to browser-sync usage,the commandline was saying "reloading browsers" but the browser was not refreshed at all, the problem was i had not included body tag in my html page where the browser-sync can inject script for its functionality,make sure your html page has body tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out: browser-sync doesn't like implicit html tags, so this (although valid HTML5) will not work:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>implicit</title>
```

but this will:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>full doc</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually it just needs body tag (and it's documented behavior)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. However I can't seem to find this in BrowserSync's documentation. Or is this a Gulp thing?

Comment: Should be in the main docs, but it's mentioned here https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync#requirements